# How to get Child Items in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I have a JSON format

```
{
    "identifier": "id",
    "items": [{
        "id": 0,
        "duration": 1,
        "startdate": "2011-11-24",
        "percentage": 0,
        "name": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
        "taskOwner": "RAK",
        "children": [{
            "id": 1,
            "duration": 20,
            "startdate": "2011-11-26",
            "percentage": 40,
            "name": "Aquire fox",
            "taskOwner": "Fox",
            "previousTaskId": "",
            "children": [{
                "id": 2,
                "duration": 40,
                "startdate": "2011-11-28",
                "percentage": 70,
                "name": "Obtain Dog",
                "taskOwner": "Dog",
                "previousTaskId": "1",
                "children": [{
                    "id": 3,
                    "duration": 60,
                    "startdate": "2011-11-25",
                    "percentage": 80,
                    "name": "Fox does his jump",
                    "taskOwner": "jump",
                    "previousTaskId": "3",
                    "children": []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to access it with the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${page.url.context}/res/components/gant_chart/css/claro.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "${page.url.context}/res/components/gant_chart/css/gantt.css";
    </style>
    <script src='${page.url.context}/res/components/gant_chart/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function () {
            var temp = eval('(${results})'); //CALLING JSON DATA
            dojoConfig = {
                async: false,
                parseOnLoad: true
            };
            dojo.require("dojo.parser");
            dojo.require("dojox.gantt.GanttChart");
            dojo.require("dojo._base.declare");
            dojo.require("dojo.query");
            dojo.require("dojox.gantt.GanttProjectItem");
            dojo.require("dojox.gantt.GanttTaskItem");
            dojo.require("dojo.dom");
            dojo.require("dojo.domReady");
            dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
                var ganttChart = new dojox.gantt.GanttChart({
                    readOnly: true,
                    height: 400, // optional: chart height in pixel, default is 400px
                    width: 1000,
                    withResource: true
                }, "gantt");

                for (var i = 0; i < temp.items.length; i++) {
                    var projectItem = temp.items[i];
                    var startDate = projectItem.startdate.split("-");
                    var project = new dojox.gantt.GanttProjectItem({
                        id: projectItem.id,
                        name: projectItem.name,
                        startDate: new Date(startDate[0], (parseInt(startDate[1]) - 1), startDate[2]),
                    });

                    var Tasks = projectItem.tasks;
                    for (var j = 0; j < Tasks.length; j++) {
                        var Task = Tasks[j];
                        var starttime = Task.startdate.split("-")
                        var task = new dojox.gantt.GanttTaskItem({
                            id: Task.id,
                            name: Task.name,
                            startTime: new Date(starttime[0], (parseInt(starttime[1]) - 1), starttime[2]),
                            duration: Task.duration,
                            percentage: Task.percentage,
                            previousTaskId: Task.previousTaskId,
                            taskOwner: Task.taskOwner
                        });
                        project.addTask(task);
                    }
                    ganttChart.addProject(project);
                }
                ganttChart.init();
            });
        }, 0); //end of dojo.addonload function
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div class="dashlet site-welcome">
        <div class="title">Gantt chart</div>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="ganttContent" style="margin:10px;">
                <div id="gantt"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where I am doing wrong? The code is not returning the child classes as I would like. Does anybody have suggestions?

Comment: How IS it returning them?  Is it giving an error?

Comment: no its not giving error, but not able to get the chart json output.when i debugged previousTaskId is null, please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I spotted is you use

```
var Tasks = projectItem.tasks;
```

but that object does not exist.

I believe it should be:

```
var Tasks = projectItem.children;
```

---

Okay, you owe me doughnuts after all this, but mess around with something like this:

```
var recurseChildren = function(parent) {

  var tasks = parent.children;
  for (var j = 0; j < tasks.length; j++) {
    var task = tasks[j];
    var startTime = task.startdate.split("-")
    var taskItem = new dojox.gantt.GanttTaskItem({
      id: task.id,
      name: task.name,
      startTime: new Date(startTime[0], (parseInt(startTime[1]) - 1), startTime[2]),
      duration: task.duration,
      percentage: task.percentage,
      previousTaskId: task.previousTaskId,
      taskOwner: task.taskOwner
    });
    project.addTask(taskItem);

    // Keynote here -- now we repeat ourselves for each child layer.
    recurseChildren(task);
  }
}

var ganttChart = new dojox.gantt.GanttChart({
  readOnly: true,
  height: 400, 
  width: 1000,
  withResource: true
}, "gantt");

for (var i = 0; i < temp.items.length; i++) {
  var projectItem = temp.items[i];
  var startDate = projectItem.startdate.split("-");
  var project = new dojox.gantt.GanttProjectItem({
    id: projectItem.id,
    name: projectItem.name,
    startDate: new Date(startDate[0], (parseInt(startDate[1]) - 1), startDate[2]),
  });
  recurseChildren(projectItem);
  ganttChart.addProject(project);
}
ganttChart.init();
```

#### Note: there is a 99% chance this isn't going to work at first - I don't have your environment to test it out and play with it. However, try to understand what the code is doing and work with it from there. I am pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: when i tried <var Tasks = projectItem.children;> i am getting the top level json not subtasks,

Comment: That's exactly right - you have to do another level of recursion to get to the sub sub tasks. Every one of these little arrays you see here: `children": [{`, means you need to do an even deeper `for` loop.

Comment: please help me on this, i am trying to do  another level of recursion to get to the  sub tasks but unfortunately not successful.

Comment: Do you really need tasks that go 3 levels deep? Is that what you intended? Did you make this JSON array, or did someone else? Or are all three tasks supposed to be of the same importance, and not really children of each other at all?

Comment: yes unfortunately even i have more than that, means 10 to 15 level, all three tasks are with same importance. we are displaying projects and its dependencies. so it will loop.

Comment: Then you are going to have to get into recursive functions. Isn't that a little steep for just getting into Javascript? Google around on recursive functions.

Comment: could you please help me on this( with sample code) i am tryig to  get into recursive functions, i dont know much about this.

Comment: Aaaalright, I put something together for you above. See my update.

Comment: thanks, it worked, you are a saviour for me.thanks once again, yep:) i owe you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `projectItem.tasks` -- there is no `tasks` property inside that array. Target `.children` instead.

Comment: i have tried children also still i am not able to get the child item, please suggest